# How do you create a custom category widget that you can style?

Tags: php, theme-development, widgets

My first time developing a WordPress theme, and I'm having a hard time understanding the widgets portion of it.  Mainly because of my limited understanding of PHP.

This is what I want my categories to look like that is currently hard coded:

```
      <!-- Categories -->
  <div class="col-lg-3 d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-block " id="categoryContainer">
    <div id="categories">
      CATEGORIES
    </div>

    <a href="" class="categoryLink">
      <div class="row px-0 mx-0">
        <div class="categoryItems col-auto me-auto px-0">Test</div>
        <div class="categoryItemCount col-auto px-0">(10)</div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <hr class="my-0 categoryDivider">

    <a href="" class="categoryLink">
      <div class="row px-0 mx-0">
        <div class="categoryItems col-auto me-auto px-0">Test</div>
        <div class="categoryItemCount col-auto px-0">(10)</div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <hr class="my-0 categoryDivider">

    <a href="" class="categoryLink">
      <div class="row px-0 mx-0">
        <div class="categoryItems col-auto me-auto px-0">Test</div>
        <div class="categoryItemCount col-auto px-0">(10)</div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <hr class="my-0 categoryDivider">

    <a href="" class="categoryLink">
      <div class="row px-0 mx-0">
        <div class="categoryItems col-auto me-auto px-0">Test</div>
        <div class="categoryItemCount col-auto px-0">(10)</div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <hr class="my-0 categoryDivider">

    <a href="" class="categoryLink">
      <div class="row px-0 mx-0">
        <div class="categoryItems col-auto me-auto px-0">Test</div>
        <div class="categoryItemCount col-auto px-0">(10)</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

[image]

How do I go about adding this as a widget?  I added a function, however, I was following a tutorial for creating a widget but it wasn't specific to categories and I'm not able to find a way to be able to style it to look like the code above.

I also don't mind hard-coding it in with the categories, but then the issue is how do I get the corresponding post count for that category?

Comment: Normally you wouldn't. The latest versions of WordPress have a built in categories block that can be added as a widget. The theme's job is just to apply styles to the markup that WordPress provides.

Comment: @JacobPeattie In that case, what is WordPress using for the categories that I can override its classes or even manually edit it?  I'm having a hard time finding that information.

Comment: Here's a [tutorial explaining custom blocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/create-block/) you can use one to facilitate the custom category functionality you're seeking. The official [gutenberg block library](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples) also contains lots of examples you can work from.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @admcfajn Thanks for the links!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)